# convert a csvLine.split String array into float

Tags: java, android, arrays, csv

I am using android studio for my college work and I have run into a problem when I try to use two parts of a `csvLine.split` String array for GPS coordinates. I get the error

> cannot resolve constructor Geopoint (java.language.string, java.language.string)

How can I convert `ids[3]` and `ids[4]` from a string value to a float value?

```
int i = 0;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
try {
    String csvLine;
    while ((csvLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        ids=csvLine.split(",");
        try{
            Log.e("CSV file row "+ i, " "+ids[0] + ", " + ids[1]+ ", " + ids[2]+ ", " + ids[3]+ ", " + ids[4]) ;
            i++;

          //  GeoPoint csvGeoPoint = new GeoPoint(ids[3], ids[4]);  //The issue is here

          //  items = new ItemizedIconOverlay<>(this, new ArrayList<OverlayItem>(), markerGestureListener);
          //  OverlayItem you = new OverlayItem(ids[1], ids[2], (csvGeoPoint));
          //  items.addItem(you);
          //  mv.getOverlays().add(items);

        }
```

The line

```
Log.e("CSV file row "+ i, " "+ids[0] + ", " + ids[1]+ ", " + ids[2]+ ", " + ids[3]+ ", " + ids[4]) ;
```

Displays these four lines from my csv file. the last two I will use for my `geoPoints` so that why they would be floats or doubles.

```
**E/CSV file row 0:**  The View, Hotel, A massive hotel, 50.9283421, -1.3928653
**E/CSV file row 1:**  TGI Fridays, Restaurant, A lovely place, 50.9050199, -1.4133411
**E/CSV file row 2:**  Weather Spoons, Bar, Your average pub, 50.9039012, -1.4078481
**E/CSV file row 3:**  Oceania, Club, A huge club, 50.9019739, -1.4161856
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to convert ids[3] and ids[4] from a string value to a float
>   value. May any one show me how i can do this.

Simply do this:

```
double num1 = Double.parseDouble(ids[3]);
double num2 = Double.parseDouble(ids[4]);
```

if as you've said your `GeoPoint` needs two doubles for its constructor then this would be valid.

```
GeoPoint csvGeoPoint = new GeoPoint(num1, num2);
```